# CKEditor не сохраняет Alt текст

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Помогите получить Alt текст для изображения при использовании своего шаблона *createFromHtml*

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    var editor = ev.editor;
    if (dialogName == 'image') {
       dialogDefinition.onOk = function(e) {
          var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;
          var imgHtml = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<div class='img'><a href="+ imageSrcUrl + "><img class='img-responsive' src=" + imageSrcUrl + " alt='' /></a></div>");
          editor.insertElement(imgHtml);
       };
    }
});
```

При загрузке изображения, прописываю ALT, но редактор не сохраняет его.
Я так понимаю что нужно получить его аналогично imageSrcUrl, но не могу понять как. Пробовал прописать txtAlt, не помогает.

Спасибо.

Comment: В код перед строкой `var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;` поставьте `console.log(e.sender.originalElement.$);` и загляните в консоль браузера. Может среди свойств выведенного объекта будет видно нужное.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем способе каждое изображение идет вместе с ссылкой на самого себя. А если нужно разместить изображение с ссылкой на страницу сайта? Или мелкое изображение (иконку), которому не нужен класс `img-responsive`?

Есть иной способ достичь той же цели. Использую его в своих проектах. Настраивается в несколько шагов:

### Шаг 1. Переключаемый стиль для изображения

Наверняка вы используете аддон [stylescombo](http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylescombo). Вот он:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Список стилей можно (и нужно) менять, через `config.stylesSet`. Причем стили можно создавать не только инлайновые или абзацевые, но и уникальные для объектов разных типов. В том числе - для изображений. Вот нужный нам код для изображения:

```
config.stylesSet = [
  {
    name: 'Само-ссылка',
    type: 'widget',
    widget: 'image',
    attributes: {
      "class": 'img-with-link'
    }
  }
]
```

Теперь, когда в редакторе у вас выделено изображение, в `stylescombo` вы можете включать и выключать пункт "Само-ссылка". Это будет добавлять к вашему изображению класс `img-with-link`. И с этим классом мы будем работать уже в режиме просмотра.

### Шаг 2. Ненавязчивое добавление само-ссылки

Ваш пост сохранен и мы видим его на странице. У изображения есть класс `img-with-link`. Теперь мы можем ненавязчиво загрузить js-скрипт, найти в нем все изображения с таким классом, и сделать с ними, что хотим. Я делаю так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = $('.img-with-link');
  if (images.length) {
    images.each(function() {
      $(this).wrap("<a href='" + $(this).attr('src') + "' target='_blank'></a>");
    });
  }
});
```

Каждое изображение я ненавязчиво оборачиваю ссылкой на само изображение с `target="_blank"`, чтобы ссылка открывалась в новой вкладке. При желании здесь же можно подключить и js-лайтбокс или js-галерею. Или добавить к самому изображению класс `img-responsive` (хотя я рекомендую просто все изображения внутри поста стилизовать так же, как стилизует класс `img-responsive`).

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Очень пригодится в будущем. Теперь понял как делать свои стили. По теме, частично решил проблему получением ALT. Получаю его по ID, но сохраняется только первое слово из Alt текста. `var txtAlt = document.getElementById('cke_641_textInput').value;` не могу понять как получить весь текст, а не только первое слово до пробела

Answer (score 1):

Решение вопроса:

```
var txtAlt = document.getElementById('cke_641_textInput').value.replace(/ /g, '\xa0');
```

Вывод Alt:

```
alt=" + txtAlt + "
```