# Обратное действие при нажатии той же кнопки в Ckeditor 4.5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как в Ckeditor 4.5.x сделать обратное действие по нажатию той же самой кнопки? Например, как это происходит при нажатии кнопки `B` (жирного шрифта).

Пример кода, который вставляет тег  ...  в выделенный текст:

```
var PlugName = 'norss';
var PlugDesc = 'Исключить из RSS';
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( PlugName, {
icons: PlugName,
init: function( editor ) {
    if ( editor.ui.addButton ) {
        editor.ui.addButton( PlugName, {
            label: PlugDesc,
            command: PlugName,
            toolbar: 'insert'
        } );
    }
    editor.addCommand( PlugName, {
        exec: function( editor ) {
            var sel = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<span class="no_rss">' + editor.getSelectedHtml(true) + '</span>' );
            editor.insertElement( sel );
        }
    });
},
} );
```

Необходимо, чтобы кнопка отображалось как нажатая при наведении\выделении кода, который находится внутри этого , а при "отжатии" это кнопки, убирался этот тег.

Answer (score 2):

Аддон `basicstyles` (который добавляет на панель кнопки `b`, `i`, `s` и ряд других), по видимому, работает с внутренним API CKEditor, включая/отключая эти стили. Я изучал внутренности `basicstyles`, явного кода по снятию стиля не нашел. Но решение есть, и оно достаточно простое.

Есть другой стандартный для CKEditor аддон - [stylescombo](http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylescombo). Выглядит он так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете изменять стили в селекте, и абзацевые, и инлайновые. Под вашу задачу подойдет инлайновый стиль, вот так он будет встраиваться в `config` CKEditor'а:

```
config.stylesSet = [
  {
    name: 'Исключить из RSS',
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {
      "class": 'no_rss'
    }
  }
]
```

Теперь в редакторе вы можете выделять любой текст и выбирать в этом селекте пункт "Исключить из RSS". К тексту будет применен класс `no_rss`.

Точно так же вы сможете выделять любой текст (или просто ставить внутрь курсор) с уже имеющимся таким классом и в селекте снимать свой выбор с пункта "Исключить из RSS". Класс будет удаляться.

Также о `stylescombo` я писал в вопросе "[CKEditor не сохраняет Alt текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561559/217849)".